# How to use tenses in participial phrases

Tags: tenses, participles

In one of my grammar books, it states -  when using a past part ending (d, ed, en, t) the action takes place prior to the finite verb. You must find the verb first and then make sure the action of past part ending is before the finite.

When using "ing", the action must be at the same time as finite. But my book gives this -

> Having declined in June, the stock market rose in July.

This example did not occur at the same time.

Comment: Please provide actual sentence examples—as well as a clear explanation of what you're asking, specifically. You've made a lot of statements, but haven't actually asked a question yet.

Comment: @JasonBassford There was an example mixed into the text, I've split it out.

Comment: "having" is an auxiliary in that sentence.

Comment: Throw the grammar book away. It's totally wrong, and has confused you. The _having_ auxiliary indicates a prior decline. The _-ing_ part is simply the active participial suffix and has nothing to do with tense or time.

Comment: Let me rephrase it -  After declining in June, stock prices rose in July.   Now, if present part ending (ing) is supposed to occur at the same time as verb, in this example it doesn't -  declining is present, rose is past.

Comment: The present participle is without tense. For example (1) *After declining in 2023, the stock market **was** rising in 2024.* (2) *After declining in 2023, the stock market **is** rising in 2024.* (3) *After declining in 2023, the stock market **will be** rising in 2024.* All three versions are possible in the right context. Yet, the verb tense that follows in the second part of each sentence is past, present, and future, respectively.